# jQuery Hover Problem - Hover Triggers on Mouse Move

Tags: jquery, hover

For reference: http://www.favsav.com/-public

You'll notice that if you hover over a list item, the meta data slides up. If you leave your mouse still on top, and then move a smidgen to the left or right, it triggers again. There's some other silliness going on if you move around

The code is pretty simple:

```
    $('li.post').hover(function(){
        $(this).find('.meta').slideDown('fast');
    }, function(){
        $(this).find('.meta').slideUp('fast');
    })
```

Any idea why things are behaving like this?

This seems to only be happening in Firefox (i'm using 3.5.5 on OSX)

**UPDATE** After restarting Firefox, all is well! Thanks for the input!

Comment: what browser?. Seems to work fine in Chrome, FF3 and IE8 (tho IE8 needs a look at)

Comment: @majman" OOps, I did say (in Maxim's post) it works on IE8, but not 100%, the "source:" value text got into the next line and only top half of the line is visible.

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, **I'm not able to reproduce this behavior** in Google Chrome 3.0.195.33. To me, it seems that this might just be **an issue with the rendering/javascript handling in your browser**. What browser are you using? The code looks OK.

**UPDATE:** Seeing as how the problem was resolved with a reboot of Firefox, and that it was un-reproducible, it seems that your code is A-OK. Good luck!

Comment: Just checked - this seems to only be happening in Firefox (i'm using 3.5.5 on OSX)... I'll do some checking on some other machines

Answer (score 0):

If this does happen to you, try setting a height & width on the element you're hovering over.